# how to scroll to set the bottom of a DIV at the bottom of the screen (monitor)

Tags: javascript, html

There is a `DIV` in my website and its height is not fixed. when user moves the mouse on an image this `DIV` will be appeared and will display some information about the image. there are several images in a grid format on page and every one has its own information. clearly some images are at bottom of the screen so by `mouseover` some section of its information `DIV` will be off the screen. I want to automatically control this situation and when any section of its `DIV` is off the screen then the scrollbar goes down until it reaches the bottom of the `DIV`.

this is my pseudo code but I could not implement it in jquery.

1. calculate `screenHeight`
2. calculate `divHeight`
3. calculate `divDistanceFromTopOfScreen`

**if** (`screenHeight` < `divHeight` + `divDistanceFromTopOfScreen`)  **then**

```
    scroll down to bottom of `DIV`
```

if you think this algorithm is right how can I implement such thing?

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

**Javascript:**

```
var top = $('.theDiv').offset().top;     // the top of your div relative to the document
var div_height = $('.theDiv').height();  // the height of your div
window.scrollTo(0, top + div_height);    // scroll to the bottom of your div
```

**References:**

- jQuery Offset: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/NGDBL/

Comment: Please implement your code and make sure that it works before posting here ! besides that top of `DIV` must be relative to screen not document

Comment: You're obviously new here.  A word of advice.  People here are trying to help you.  If someone helps you in a way that you don't necessarily find useful, rather than screaming at them, you might start with a "thanks, but...".  You'll make more friends here that way.  :-)

Comment: Indeed I am grateful for your reply, I just gave you an advice to post more useful posts in future my friend ;)